# Does libgit2 support SSH-Transport-Protocol?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

Is it possible to clone a repository via ssh using ssh-keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSH transport is not yet implemented in libgit2.

Check  <strike>[issue 1103](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1103)</strike> [issue 1558](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1558) for progress.

### Update

Pull request **[1508](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1558)**  **has been merged** on May, 16th 2013.

Since then, it's also been well taken care of (cf. **[1706](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1706)**, **[1717](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1717)**, **[1775](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1775)**, **[1851](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1851)**, **[1903](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1903)**, **[1904](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1904)**).

It's even now continuously tested on Travis (cf. **[1774](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/1774)**).

Comment: Is this available in libgit2sharp too?

Comment: any tips how to get this working? Looks like it needs libssh2 - how do I use a ssh-clone/fetch/pull/push on windows?

Comment: @user1130329 libssh2 will work on Windows. [The build instructions for libgit are here](https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/build-and-link/).