# How to use SSH support in libgit2?

Tags: c, git, cmake, libgit2

As i see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204015/does-libgit2-support-ssh-transport-protocol), `libgit2` is now supporting use of ssh repository urls.

But how to force it to work? as i understood from CMakeLists file, SSH support will be enabled automatically if `libssh2` library will be detected.

```
IF(NOT LIBSSH2_LIBRARY)
    FIND_PACKAGE(LIBSSH2 QUIET)
ENDIF()
IF (LIBSSH2_FOUND)
    MESSAGE("libssh2 was detected!")
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DGIT_SSH)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBSSH2_INCLUDE_DIR})
    SET(SSH_LIBRARIES ${LIBSSH2_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF()
```

As it has to be, i saw the "libssh2 was detected" message.
However, the macro `GIT_SSH` after cmake work is still undefined, and all of SSH stuff is unavailable.
For example, code `git_cred_ssh_keyfile_passphrase kf_pass;` does not compile.
I get such error: 
`'git_cred_ssh_keyfile_passphrase' was not declared in this scope`,
i.e. `GIT_SSH` is undefined because this structure is declared in `#ifdef GIT_SSH ... #endif` block.

Maybe i'm do something in a wrong way?

Comment: What exact error are you getting? How have you determined that `GIT_SSH` isn't being defined?

Comment: @CarlosMartínNieto The error is `'git_cred_ssh_keyfile_passphrase' was not declared in this scope`. This structure is declared in `#ifdef GIT_SSH` block in libgit2. So, i'm sure this macro is undefined. But it shouldn't be!

Comment: Make sure you clean your build directory. I could only reproduce any issue when working from a dirty build dir from before the option made it into the dev branch.

Comment: @CarlosMartínNieto I'm just convert `libgit2` make system from `cmake` to Qt's `qmake` because this library is using in large Qt/qmake project. So, my question became "deprecated", heh. But thanks for tip.